# can't send email usign amazon SES from development enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ses

I'm trying to change my mandrilapp configuration to amazon ses in order to send emails from my rails app, but when I try to test, rails does not gave any error, but the email never array.

I have two verified address from my ses management console, but I don't understand why I can't send emails.

I have the following configuration:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :aws_sdk

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address   => "email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
    :port      => 465,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :user_name => "blablablausername",
    :password  => "blablablablablablapassword", 
    :authentication => 'login',
    :ssl => true,
    :domain => 'mydomain.es', 
  }
```

any idea?

Thanks

UPDATE

---

I uploaded my code to heroku but when I sign up to create a new user I get the following error:

> Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError (unable to sign request without
>   credentials set)

but as you can see I have my user and pass credential.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: perhaps it's because your host/domain in the development environment is `localhost` and does match your domain in the configuration?

Comment: maybe, but is any way to test before upload to production?

Comment: Did you add the "credentials" to the `production.rb`? Sorry to ask so dump questions ;)

Comment: It's ok @Mark I think my credential are:  :user_name => "blablablausername", :password  => "blablablablablablapassword" and I have this on my production file. But I don't know if those are the credentials that I need.

Comment: @Mark I solve my problem with the credentials, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully shipped an app using SES with the following setup.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'aws-ses', '~> 0.6.0', require: 'aws/ses'

# config/initializers/amazon_ses.rb
ActionMailer::Base.add_delivery_method :ses, AWS::SES::Base,
  access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.amazon_access_key,
  secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.amazon_secret_key,
  server: 'email.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'

# config/environments/development(or production).rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :ses
```

You must also set the default URL options - `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`.

More information is available on the [GitHub README](https://github.com/drewblas/aws-ses#rails).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to make this work without a gem.